# PSPICE: How to change the axes in simulation?

Tags: simulation, pspice

I am getting V on both the axes? I need a I- V Curve of zener diode characteristics

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the axis settings and then run a DC sweep. You can change the x and y axis settings and the window should look like the picture below. Make sure you change the axis variable. You will then get a whole list of voltage and current outputs across multiple elements in your circuit.

[image]

If you're still confused, try looking look at [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWPSpHqPPi0) YouTube video.

Answer (score 0):

In the schematic capture window, place a VDC part in parallel with your zener diode. For the sake of this discussion, I'll assume the VDC part's reference designation is **V1**. Wire V1's positive (+) terminal to the zener's cathode, and wire V1's negative (-) terminal to the zener's anode. Wire a ground reference (the '0' zero part) to the wire that connects V1's negative (-) terminal to the zener's anode.

In the schematic capture window, create a new simulation profile and select **DC Sweep** as the *Analysis Type*. Select voltage source **V1** as your *Sweep Variable*. The *Sweep Type* is **Linear** with a *Start Value* of **-1.5V**, and *End Value* that is one or two volts greater than the zener voltage (e.g., if \$V_{Z}=6\$ choose an *End Value* of 7V), and an *Increment* value of **1mV**. Click on **OK** to save these changes and close the *Simulation Settings* dialog.

In the schematic capture window, attach a **Current Marker** probe to the zener diode's cathode lead.

In the schematic capture window, save these changes to your project.

In the schematic capture window, press the keyboard's F11 key to run the selected PSpice simulation profile (which, presumably, is the DC Sweep simulation profile you just created). The AMS Simulator window will render a plot of the zener current (Y-axis) vs. zener voltage (X-axis).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and started a short review in my engineering notes, then I found the solution. If you have created your circuit with SPICE codes just simply add it to the rest of your code:
.TRAN 500us 100ms 0s 500us UIC

Electronic bless ;)